# PHP DOMDocument. Как обратиться к первому элементу?

Tags: php, xml, dom

Есть очень простой XML-файл со следующим содержанием:

```
<sst />
```

Каким образом можно обратиться к элементу sst и создать в нем другой элемент si, добавив его в конец? Как вариант, но хотелось бы обратиться к элементу напрямую, без перебора...

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $dom->load($file);


        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagname('sst') as $e) {

            $element = $dom->createElement('si', '');
            $e->appendChild($element);

        }


        echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML());
```

Пишу что-то вроде $element = $dom->firstChild->createElement(), но получаю ошибку...

Answer (score 0):

Вот, нашел решение:

```
$element = $dom->createElement('si', '');
$dom->firstChild->appendChild($element);
```